# Compute the mean of a data blob during testing phase

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I am using hdf5 layer that has data and label.

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./list.txt"
    batch_size: 8
    shuffle: true
  }
}
```

During the testing phase, it will load 8 images from the testing set and feed the network. I would like to print the mean value of each image during the testing phase. Is it possible to use it in CAFFE? Which layer should I used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`"Reduction"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/reduction.html) layer

```
layer {
  type: "Reduction"
  name: "img_mean"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "img_mean"
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
    axis: 0  # to reduce the entire batch, or axis: 1 for per-image mean
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is right. But it has minor typo. It must be Reduction